# How can I have the same index for two different columns where the columns do not have unqiue values?

Tags: pandas

df1:

| name_d | name_o | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turkiye | Italy | 1990 |
| Turkiye | Italy | 1991 |
| Turkiye | Italy | 1993 |
| Spain | Italy | 1990 |
| Spain | Italy | 1991 |
| Spain | Japan | 1990 |

df2:

| country_name | year | v2x_regime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Spain | 1990 | 0 |
| Turkiye | 1990 | 0 |
| Italy | 1990 | 1 |
| Turkiye | 1991 | 1 |
| Spain | 1991 | 1 |
| Italy | 1991 | 1 |

Expected result:

| name_o | v2x_regime_name_o | name_d | v2x_regime_name_d | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | 1 | Turkiye | 1 | 1990 |

Basically I would like to know the regime type of the each country for each year. Since this is a bilateral data, there are two columns that include country name. For example, for each year I would like to have the index for name_o column and name_d column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['name_o','year'], right_on=['country_name','year'], how='left')
df = df.merge(df2, left_on=['name_d,'year'], right_on=['country_name','year'], how='left')
```

Comment: I do the same but I would like to have more efficient codes since the two datasets are so big and I only wanna use one index from the big dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient'. Such code should not take long to run even on a large number of rows.

Comment: more compact I might say instead of efficient. But if it is not possible I can use those lines. Many thanks @gtomer.

Comment: Do that and then drop un needed columns